# How do I make my CSS/HTML category menu minimize gracefully when a user minimizes the browser window?

Tags: html, css, menu, height, minimize

### My Problem

When I minimize the browser window the category menu does not minimize the way I would like it to. I would like the **li** elements to drop one by one below the other other **li** elements as the window is minimized. The problem is that the whole **ul** element is dropped below the **p** element.

A live example of the [menu is located here](http://jsbin.com/aguwu4). 
The live example's [code is located here.](http://jsbin.com/aguwu4/edit)

Here is the category menu in a full size window. Notice the Main Categories and Sub Categories gray **p** DIVS are not at max-height even though I have set their height to 100%. The orange and yellow DIVs are called **#main** and **#sub**. The purple DIV is the **ul** element and the lightly colored blocks with text in them are the **li** elements.
[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08FsFrA4I/AAAAAAAAAFw/hZm7flu032A/cat-full-size.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08FsFrA4I/AAAAAAAAAFw/hZm7flu032A/cat-full-size.jpg)

Here it is in a 861px wide window. No change...
[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08GYxMMhI/AAAAAAAAAF0/nFpr-pV3eF4/cat-861px.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08GYxMMhI/AAAAAAAAAF0/nFpr-pV3eF4/cat-861px.jpg)

Here it is in a 777px window. Here you can see the entire purple **ul** element in the yellow **#sub** DIV just drops below the gray Sub Categories **p** element
[alt text http://lh5.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08H2tAA8I/AAAAAAAAAF4/VH5Wo46HCgg/cat-777px.jpg](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08H2tAA8I/AAAAAAAAAF4/VH5Wo46HCgg/cat-777px.jpg)

Here it is in a 731px window. Here we can see the purple **ul** element in the orange **#main** DIV also drops below the Main Categories **p** element.
[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08IUMAXRI/AAAAAAAAAF8/pqmPpOgVv_Y/cat-731px.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08IUMAXRI/AAAAAAAAAF8/pqmPpOgVv_Y/cat-731px.jpg)

Here it is in a 721px window. Finally we can see that the **li** elements begin to drop down a level as the yellow **#sub** DIV minimzes even more.

### The Solution I Seek

Now I would like to show you the results I am after with mock ups I constructed in Photoshop.

Here we can see the gray **p** element containing the text Main Categories and Sub Categories are now at the full height of their **#main** and **#sub** containing DIVs. Also and more importantly, we can see that the entire **ul** element no longer drops below the gray **p** element.
[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08LBmFWnI/AAAAAAAAAGM/WLQx_wVsSQw/cat-correct-777px.jpg](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08LBmFWnI/AAAAAAAAAGM/WLQx_wVsSQw/cat-correct-777px.jpg)

And finally we can see **#main** DIVs purple **ul** element minimize propely just as the **#sub** DIVs purple **ul** element did in the screen shot above.
[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08L0F5OoI/AAAAAAAAAGQ/isdjLp6m_rs/cat-correct-731px.jpg](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_rNlSpSUBkYo/TF08L0F5OoI/AAAAAAAAAGQ/isdjLp6m_rs/cat-correct-731px.jpg)

Full size images of the images here can be seen at my [Picassa album](http://picasaweb.google.com/104531327405618516468/CategoryMenuMinimizeProblem#)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was to add `display: table;` to the `ul` element and get rid of `float:left`. Now it minimizes as I would like across Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera and Safa Here is the [link to the new updated code](http://jsbin.com/aguwu4/6/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the time to finish this but after working on it this is what I got:
(Posting here cause the save function didn't seem to work).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Categories DIV Problem
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
      /*** GLOBAL ***/

      *
      {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        outline: none;
      }

      html, body
      {
        height: 100%;
        font: .9em Arial ,san-serif;
      }

      ul, li
      {
        list-style: none;
      }

      .clear
      {
        clear: both;
      }  

      /*** PAGE ***/

      #container
      {
        max-width: 1000px;
        width: 85%;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      /*** CATEGORIES ***/

      #categories
      {

        height: 100%;
        /* padding: 20px; */
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      }

      #main
      {
        background: orange;
        height:50px;

      }

      #sub
      {
        background: yellow;
      }

      #cat-main
      {

      }

      #cat-sub
      {
        float: left;
      }

      .cat-name-box
      {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ddd;
      }

      .cat-choice-box
      {
        width:auto;
        background: purple;

      }


      #categories li
      {
        float: left;
        padding: 3px 8px;
        margin: 1px;
      }

      #cat-main li
      {
        background: #D7B0FF;
      }

      #cat-main li:hover
      {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #9A38FF;
        color: #fff;
      }  

      #cat-sub li
      {
        background: #85FF87;
      }

      #cat-sub li:hover
      {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #00C403;
        color: #fff;
      }    

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="categories">
        <div id="main">
          <div class="cat-name-box">Main Categories</div>
          <ul class="cat-choice-box" id="cat-main">
            <li>Technology</li>
            <li>Politics</li>
            <li>Business</li>
            <li>Science</li>
            <li>Music</li>
            <li>Film</li>
            <li>Art</li>
            <li>Health</li>
            <li>Sports</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problem is the height set on the container of the text + ul, it has to be set for the p-element(I changed it to div I think, can't remember why)to inherit the 100% height.

Hope this kind of helps though I know this isn't the entire solution.

Comment: @Rawkward thanks but the problem is that the height can not be set to a fixed hieght like 50px because 1.) If there are only a few categories then we have space for two rows of categories when we only need space for one row. This is the case when the browser window is maximized. 2.) If there are more categories added later and the window is minimized we may need more than 2 rows for the <li> elements to fall into. What I am seeking is a way for the height of the #sub and #main divs to expand in height when the window is minimized so it can fit extra <li> elements that squish.

Comment: I know, like I said, not an entire solution.

You could probably do it easily with jQuery if CSS doesn't allow this behaviour. If so make a fixed width version first, then if javascript is disabled you'd still have a decent menu, only with a horizontal scrollbar on smaller windows.

Question, is this html structure neccesary or will any other do? if the result is the same?